# Query Caching in PHP For mySQL Performance

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm looking for a system to cache an already coded project (with PHP) which has features like registration and login system etc.

I have searched for some caching solutions, but I read that the logging in and posting system fails if I use such features.

What I actually need is to store results of some spesific DB queries, if there's a cache, call that results, if not generate a new cache, and re-cache them in each x minutes. (results can be stored in txt. etc).

How can I do that?

By the way, setting query_cache_type to 1 don't work. I'm looking for alternative solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Probably this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672029/best-technique-for-caching-results-from-queries-that-change-infrequently

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you need to cache the query:

```
 # After: [with memcache]
    $rSlowQuery = mysql_query_cache($sql);
    # $rSlowQuery is an array
    $rows = count($rSlowQuery);
    for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) { }
```

Answer (score 7):

**Reduce Database Calls**
Check out [phpFastCache](http://www.phpfastcache.com) that support WinCache, MemCache, Files, X-Cache, APC Cache. It's simple for beginners

> PHP Caching Class For Database : Your website have 10,000 visitors who
>   are online, and your dynamic page have to send 10,000 same queries to
>   database on every page load. With phpFastCache, your page only send 1
>   query to DB, and use the cache to serve 9,999 other visitors.

```
<?php
    // In your config file
    include("php_fast_cache.php");
    // This is Optional Config only. You can skip these lines.
    // phpFastCache support "apc", "memcache", "memcached", "wincache" ,"files", "pdo", "mpdo" and "xcache"
    // You don't need to change your code when you change your caching system. Or simple keep it auto
    phpFastCache::$storage = "auto";
    // End Optionals

    // In your Class, Functions, PHP Pages
    // try to get from Cache first.
    $products = phpFastCache::get("products_page");

    if($products == null) {
        $products = YOUR DB QUERIES || GET_PRODUCTS_FUNCTION;
        // set products in to cache in 600 seconds = 10 minutes
        phpFastCache::set("products_page",$products,600);
    }

    foreach($products as $product) {
        // Output Your Contents HERE
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into an similar issue, and here's how I resolved it...

---

**Step 1:** Add a `.user.ini` file to your project root (if you don't already have one), and the following directives to the file to enable the `mysqlnd_qc` plugin and set a TTL for the cache:

```
; Enables MySQL query caching by PHP
mysqlnd_qc.enable_qc = 1

; Set a default TTL for the caching in seconds
mysqlnd_qc.ttl = 30
```

**Step 2:** Add a SQL hint before any query you want cached by mysqlnd_qc.

*Here's the hint that must be added to the query:*

```
"/*" . MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH . "*/" .
```

*Here's an example of use:*

```
$res = $mysqli->query("/*" . MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH . "*/" . "SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = 1");
```

---

That should do it! You could also cache all queries using the `mysqlnd_qc.cache_no_table = 1` directive.

All of this comes from PHP's documentation, here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$mysqli -> query("/*qc=on*/ SELECT * FROM table");
```